# trying to query from Netezza in Python: Can't open lib '/usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pyodbc, netezza

Im trying to query data from Netezza and I am just unable to do it from a linux machine.I am breaking my head over this error for the past 3 days. My code is pretty simple

The error I get is:

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: This question has the jupyter-notebook tag. Are you running python standalone or in a notebook? Have you actually installed the Netezza ODBC driver?

Comment: I did install the driver in /usr/local/nz folder :)